# 403 Error when starting Strapi Media Library on my Plesk Server

Tags: media, strapi, http-status-code-403

I loaded my Strapi CMS via git on my Plesk Server. Everything is working well. Only the Media Library doesn't work. I'm not able to create a folder or uploading a picture.

It always says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
In the console

The folder has all rights for writing.

Has anyone an idea?

I checked the permission to write in the upload folder.